# PDF loading but not saving laravel DOMPDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf, laravel-blade

I can generate the pdf however it is not saving for some reason. The directory ../public/cover_images does exist

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('sell.contractpdf',['contracts' => $contracts]);
    $pdf->save('../public/cover_images');
```

All this does is display the pdf in the browser. I need it to save to the public directory on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a pdf name like

```
$pdf->save('../public/cover_images/test.pdf');
```

Comment: That worked  for me: $pdf->save('cover_images/test.pdf');